# Does RTP timestamp represents the PTS of the audio/video present in media?

Tags: video-streaming, rtsp, live-streaming

What is the correct significance of the RTP timestamps. Does they merely represent the audio, video PTS in the data?

Answer (score 1):

According to RFC3550 https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3550.txt

> The timestamp reflects the sampling instant of the first octet in the RTP data packet.

Also remember that the RTP timestamp should start with a random number

> The initial value of the timestamp SHOULD be random

You need to decode the RTCP data to find the relationship between RTP timestamps and wallclock time or other RTP streams.  Many types of video streams (eg. H.264) will also contain PTS values inside the RTP data and these should be used for decoding order and presentation rather than the RTP timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is only DTS, not PTS.

So it is impossible to send B-Frame in RTP.

Comment: This is not correct. We used to send H.264 video with all I, P and B frames in RTP session. The question I am referring is whether RTP timestamp is the snapshot of the time at the delivery of the packet or it is exactly the PTS timestamp of the frame.

Comment: RTP really has nothing to do with the type of frames that are carried inside it (in a layered architecture it doesn't care).  MPEG2-TS containing H.264 with I,BP frames can and is often sent in RTP, H.264 ES can also be sent in RTP.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, RTP timestamps represent PTS, which is significant enough. PTS can be calculated by RTP and RTCP.
ref#1: [h264 RTP timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439096/h264-rtp-timestamp)
["Non interleaved", in which, you must set the RTP timestamp to the PTS + offset]
ref#2: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/discuss-webrtc/npLmOesI8A4/oL2p_HbhAgAJ
[synchronization between two RTP streams using RTCP SR]