# How to Sync multiple IP cameras

Tags: video, video-streaming, streaming, rtsp, rtp

Is it possible for a video player to play live video from two IP Cameras for the same scene in sync?
Assumption: 
    Both cameras output RTSP H.264
    Clocks on the two camera are always accurate. 
    Of course both cameras run RTCP server.
I have searched the internet for long and could not find a certain answer.

My thoughts so far:
Since the two RTCP servers map the RTP timestamps from the two cameras to UTC time, I can sync after unpacking RTP so that the element stream are synced when pushed to decoder.
Is this correct?

Comment: What is "in sync" to you?  Without a common clock reference (frame clock, genlock, etc., not clock-on-the-wall time), each camera is going to run at its own rate.  This is never going to be exact... it will differ a bit from camera to camera, and each camera is going to produce a frame at a different time.  The only way to fix that is a common sync signal between all the cameras, and that has nothing to do with your protocol for delivery over an IP network.

Comment: Thanks Brad for your input.
Let's assume the clocks on the two cameras are ABSOLUTE accurate.
Do I still need a wall clock if both camera have accurate clock?
With the on-camera RTCP server, I should be able to get the UTC time from the RTP timestamp.
By "in sync", I mean I can measure the time difference between frames from the two cameras.
My goal is to get the UTC time when the RTP packets are created.

I understand camera clocks drift, but I can calibrate the clocks through server, say, every 10 seconds.

Comment: You're talking about a different clock.  I'm talking about a clock signal for scanning frames.

Comment: The frames don't have to be in sync THAT perfect, as you mentioned "at clock signal for scanning frames"
It's good enough as long as I can get the PTS.
Do you think the RTCP approach (in my original post) can give me the PTS?
It seems the RTP time stamp can be used to calculate PTS.
ref#1: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439096/h264-rtp-timestamp
["Non interleaved", in which, you must set the RTP timestamp to the PTS + offset]
ref#2: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/discuss-webrtc/npLmOesI8A4/oL2p_HbhAgAJ
[synchronization between two RTP streams using RTCP SR]